# Pivot Table data with split column names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table `DataDefinitions`. I wrote a query to get data from this table in following format:

[image]

but I want to separate the common name part in `Name` column and pivot result data to get records in following format:

[image]

Please help me how to do this in a SQL Server stored procedure.

My query to get first table is

```
SELECT
     d.Name
   , r.latestValueDec AS value
FROM IDReadingLatestValues r
JOIN DataDefinitions d ON r.dataDefinitionId = d.dataDefinitionId
```

Comment: Please provide your query

Comment: Is it always 3 phases? or the can be unlimited amount?

Comment: yes its always up to phase C i.e. three phases

Comment: @Devart I have provided the query in my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its always up to three phases you can use conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(t.name,'Phase A',''),'Phase B',''),'Phace C','') as name,
       max(CASE WHEN s.latestValueDesc like '%Phase A' then s.latestValueDesc end) as Phase_A,
       max(CASE WHEN s.latestValueDesc like '%Phase B' then s.latestValueDesc end) as Phase_B,
       max(CASE WHEN s.latestValueDesc like '%Phase C' then s.latestValueDesc end) as Phase_C
FROM IDReadingLatestValues s
JOIN DataDefinitions t
 ON s.dataDefinitionId = t.dataDefinitionId
GROUP BY replace(replace(replace(t.name,'Phase A',''),'Phase B',''),'Phace C','')
```

I'm sure there is a prettier way to do this, but it should work as you expect it.

Comment: No problem :) @VIVEK

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but work...

```
SELECT
     Name = SUBSTRING(d.Name, 1, PATINDEX('%Phase%', d.Name)
   , [Phase A] = SUM(CASE WHEN d.Name LIKE '%Phase A' THEN r.latestValueDec END)
   , [Phase B] = SUM(CASE WHEN d.Name LIKE '%Phase B' THEN r.latestValueDec END)
   , [Phase C] = SUM(CASE WHEN d.Name LIKE '%Phase C' THEN r.latestValueDec END)
FROM dbo.IDReadingLatestValues r
JOIN dbo.DataDefinitions d ON r.dataDefinitionId = d.dataDefinitionId
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(d.Name, 1, PATINDEX('%Phase%', d.Name)
```

PS. Please normalize your data...